# php - how to get value from an array object

Tags: php

I use php code and I have a problem with getting value of an array object. When I use `var_dump($arr)`, I get this (the code below is formatted for better readability):

```
object(League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GoogleUser)#5 (1) {
    ["response":protected]=> array(5) {
        ["emails"]=> array(1) {
            [0]=> array(1) {
                ["value"]=> string(21) "thienlam129@gmail.com"
            }
        }
        ["id"]=> string(21) "115281634466837725533"
        ["displayName"]=> string(18) "thiên lâm trần"
        ["name"]=> array(2) {
            ["familyName"]=> string(6) "trần"
            ["givenName"]=> string(11) "thiên lâm"
        }
        ["image"]=> array(1) {
            ["url"]=> string(98) "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-SpWfKGTcQt8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAB8/IlGQQnvy7so/photo.jpg?sz=50"
        }
    }
}
```

Please, tell me how to get emails value.

Comment: The object has a public `getEmail` method on it. https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-google/blob/master/src/Provider/GoogleUser.php. `$googleUser->getEmail();`

Comment: `["response":protected=> array(5) { ["emails"]` the scope of the property this is in is `protected` only properties with `public` scope can be accessed directly ( for example `$obj->response` will not work) from outside of the class. So you have to access it using a public method that returns it instead (See above)

Comment: @R.Chappell why not write this as an answer? Looks like one

Comment: FYI: This is not an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cast the object as an array as such:

```
var_dump((array) $object);
```

Or

```
$array = (array) $object;
```

And access all its properties but you might have to array walk and filter the name of the class out.

But this is a hack and an example of bad practise. Accessing protected properties by its methods is the way to go or else request json object instead, if possible.

Naturally, you would say

```
$object = (object) $inputObject;
$value = (string) $object->getValue();
```

Or

```
$value = (array) $object->getArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason you're facing this problem is probably because the object is not an array at all.

As mentioned in the comments, the [GoogleUser](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-google/blob/master/src/Provider/GoogleUser.php#L72) object has a public getEmail method which you can use to retrieve the email address.

You can use it like this:

```
$email = $googleUser->getEmail();
```

(In the above code sample I took the liberty of calling it a `$googleUser` rather than an `$arr` because it's not an arr but a google user)